# Unable to select multiple items on a muti select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I got a multiple select box as below

This is the HTML CODE

```
<select 
  name="bk_groupids" 
  id="bk_groupids" 
  multiple="multiple" 
  data-native-menu="false" 
  data-default-value="">
  <option value='1'>Ok</option>
  <option value='2'>Ok1</option>
  <option value='3'>Ok2</option>
</select>
```

When I click the button it turns blue as below but it is not showing all the items to select multiple.

[image]

How can I select multiple items from the select box?

**Update**

Just now noticed that we have to set `data-native-menu="false"`.  I just made the change and I got the error `Uncaught TypeError: a.preventDefault is not a function in jquery.min.js`

Comment: You need to use 'ctrl' + click to select multiple items if this is a regular select element.

Comment: @DinoMyte Sorry, that is not working... Its the same result.

Comment: If you're getting javascript related errors, it might be good to post that code.

Comment: @mmm I was using `jQuery 2.2.1`.  I just downgraded to `jQuery 1.12.1` and problem disappeared.  I am just thinking jquery mobile is compatible only with 1.12.1...

Comment: Well, a.preventDefault is not a function in jQuery or anything else. 

it should be a.preventDefault(); - so if you are getting a jQuery error, check the jQuery that came with your plugin for a.preventDefault and make sure it is properly syntaxed as a function call. It is very possible that the plugin developer messed up syntax.

Also, if "a" is not referencing the object in question for the handler - you will get the same reference error.

Comment: I assume you are using JQM V1.4.5. jQuery 2.2 was released after jQuery Mobile 1.4.5. See open ticket https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/8381  It will be fixed in JQM V1.4.6 and JQM V1.5.0. 
I suggest to keep using jQuery V1.12.4 for a while.